# Returning data count from a particular day after comparing 2 tables

Tags: mysql, union

Here is the dbfiddle for better understanding, refer this when reading question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0919cacb5d117450168cdc917433a45e

I have 2 tables called listings and logs table. The listings table holds a products reference number and it's current status. So suppose if it's status was Publish currently and it's sold later, the status updates to Sold. Here the refno. in this table is unique since the status can change for 1 product.

Now I have another table called Logs table, this table records all the status changes that have happened for a particular product(referenced by refno) in a particular timeframe. The initial entry in the listings table is not recorded here, but once it's status is changed, that entry is shown here.

Suppose I have the following Listings table('D' => 'Draft', 'A' => 'Action', 'Y' => 'Publish', 'S' => 'Sold', 'N' => 'Let'):

```
INSERT INTO listings VALUES
 (3, 'Y','2021-05-02','2021-10-02','LP01'), (4, 'A','2021-05-01','2021-05-01','LP02'),
 (5, 'S','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','LP03'), (6, 'N','2021-05-01','2021-10-06','LP06'), 
 (10, 'D','2021-10-06','2021-10-06','LP05'), (11, 'D','2021-01-01','2021-01-01','LP04');
```

Here as of now the total count under every status would give:

| status_1 | c |
| --- | --- |
| Publish | 1 |
| Action | 1 |
| Sold | 1 |
| Left | 1 |
| Draft | 2 |

But if I wanted only the count for entries made in 2020-10-01 it'll show 0 under all statuses except sold, where it'll show 1.

Now in this timeframe between 2020-10-01 and today, there have been values entered in listings table as shown above and also for some, the statuses have changed. Logs table:

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES
 (1, 'Let','Action','2021-06-01','LP01'), (2, 'Action','Draft','2021-10-01','LP01'), 
 (3, 'Draft','Publish','2021-10-02','LP01'), (4, 'Action','Let','2021-10-06','LP06');
```

What is being shown right now in my listings table is the values after the status change has been made. So now to get the total count on a particular day, I'm having my statement reference the dates from the logs table and respectively subtract the status_to, and add the status_from. Query for this is in the dbfiddle provided above. Here I made it to return data that happened on or before 2021-10-01 and it does not give the right output.

Another problem with this query is I cannot return the data for the entries that had initially taken place. For example like I mentioned above the value for the data on 2020-10-01 should show 1 under sold, while 0 under everything else(desired output), but it does not do this since there are no logs made in logs table for when a new entry in initially added.

So basically what I want here is for the query to check for transactions in both my tables that happened between today and the date specified in the query and reduce any transaction that have taken after the date that I have specified in my query. If you want an easier explanation for what I'm trying to achieve, please refer to this:

[image]

Comment: add another `UNION` to include applicable listing entries which do not appear in the logs, check the last query. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a4a76b3feea67e9ab56a732608223f3

Comment: @ProGu is there any possibility of achieving this without tampering with my tables? Also could you show it to me as my desired output, where for the date 2020-10-01, all statuses are 0 except for sold with 1